# Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ so that $f(x)(c−a)<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ so that $f(x)(c−a)<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

I'm so confused about how to even start this question. I've tried setting $c = (a+b) / 2$, so that it is in the interval but I have no clue what I should even be trying to achieve to get prove this statement.

The question also originally states that $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$ and that for any $c \in (a, b)$, $f$ is integrable on $[c, b]$.

[image]

Comment: I suppose $f$ is a function mapping $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R$, but which properties does it have?

Comment: f is bounded on [a, b] and that for any c ∈ (a, b), f is integrable on [c, b].

Comment: @veloxvictory please edit your question so that the premises and question are in the body of the main text - it is illegible as written right now...

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287540/prove-that-if-f-is-defined-and-bounded-in-a-b-and-integrable-in-c-b-fo?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is bounded, then there is some $M\in (0,\infty)$ such that $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. If you choose any $c\in(a,a+\epsilon/M)$, you get

$$ f(x)(c-a)\le |f(x)|\epsilon/M\le \epsilon \quad \text{for all $x\in[a,b]$.}$$

Note that this does not need integrability.